# How do I show popular videos on my YouTube homepage rather than my friend's activities?

Tags: youtube

Right now my YouTube homepage shows the activity from my friends on Google+ (and I don't have many friends there, so the last activity on my homepage was six months ago).

I have the official YouTube app for iPhone, and the homepage shows the most popular videos for the day, and it is amazing.

How can I instead show these popular videos on my homepage rather than the social feed, and rather than having to subscribe to a bunch of channels?

Answer (score 3):

YouTube shows you your *Subscriptions* page as default. You could just click the *Browse* link, and you will be taken to a list of the most popular videos, regardless of your friends'.

There does not seem to be a way to set this as the default YouTube start page, but you could always just create a bookmark for the *Browse* page.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to subscribe to [*Popular on YouTube* channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/HCtnHdj3df7iM). It is channel [auto generated by YouTube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2579942?hl=en). Subscribing will cause new videos show on your YouTube homepage.